# How to find if a function hasn't been called?

Tags: android, timer

I am working on an Android application and I just want to know when a function hasn't been called. For example, lets say you have the function

```
void foo()
{
 ...//do something here;
}
```

What I want to do is time if the function hasn't been called for lets say, 10 seconds, and then record the time after that 10 seconds. After that, if the function is invoked and it is called, I want to record the time when it function begins again. I was thinking of using the Timer function but I wasn't exactly sure on how to test whether or not a function has been invoked.

I am working on an application in which you see whether or not a person starts or stops walking. For example, if someone has stopped walking for 10 seconds, I want to record that time. When they resume walking, I also want to record that time. Hope this makes better sense. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to add a boolean flag to your code; maybe call it `fooWasCalled`. Initialize this variable to `false` and set it to `true` inside `foo()`. Then you can simply check the flag when you need to know whether or not the function was called.

This is a very common idiom to check whether some action has occurred.

p.s. Since you are using a Timer, you probably need to synchronize access to this boolean flag or use some other thread-safe mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want (not completer code, just idea)

```
protected boolean mIsCountDownOn;

private class CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 10000)
{
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish()
    {
        mIsCountDownOn = false;
    }
};
```

In foo

```
foo
{

    if (mIsCountDownOn)
    {
         // less than 10 seconds since the last time foo is called
         mCountDownTimer.cancel();
     }
     else
     {
          // more than 10 seconds since last call
          mIsCountDownOn = true;  // will start the timer at the end of foo body

          // Code to save mTime to wherever you want to save it.
     }


     // Whatever else foo supposes to do

     mTime = // get the time now
     mCountDownTimer.start();
}
```